# Parsing attributes and Values using Groovy's XmlParser

Tags: groovy

I have the following part of an XML file:

```
<properties> 
    <project.version>module.version</project.version>
    <ie.version>17-8-103</ie.version>
    <leg_uk.version>17-6-6</leg_uk.version>
    <leg_na.version>17-8-103</leg_na.version>
</properties>
```

I want to generate a file with the following content:

```
ie.project.version = 17-8-103
leg_uk.project.version = 17-8-103
```

How to generate such file?

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois re: "and what is your question?"... I think he/she wants to know how to create a text file that contains things like `project.version = 17-8-103` and `leg_uk.project.version = 17-8-103` given XML like what is shown in the question.

Comment: I want to generate given text file by parsing the given xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what You're looking for?

```
def txt = """<properties> 
    <project.version>module.version</project.version>
    <ie.version>17-8-103</ie.version>
    <leg_uk.version>17-6-6</leg_uk.version>
    <leg_na.version>17-8-103</leg_na.version>
</properties>"""
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(txt)

new File('tmp').withWriter { w ->
   xml.children().each {
      w << "${it.name()}=${it.value().text()}\n"
   }
}
```

Comment: yes.. Thank you so much. I was stuck on how to parse *.version tag. This worked... :)